# duda Port Scanner (python)

Tags: python

Estoy creando un port scanner y quiero lograr que el programa, al ingresar un host, me arroje todos los puertos que este tenga abierto, pero al hacerlo solo me da el primer puerto que está abierto.

```
    #! /usr/bin/python

import socket

# crea un socket INET de tipo STREAM
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = raw_input("Host para scan: ")
socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)

def portscanner(port):
        if sock.connect_ex((host, port)):
                None
        else:
                print "Port %d is open" % (port)

for port in range(1,10000):
        portscanner(port)
```

El resultado:

```
Host para scan: 10.0.10.1
Port 22 is open
```

de antemano, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usar el siguiente código:

```
for port in range(1, 1025):  
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
    if result == 0:
        print "Port {}:      Open".format(port)
    sock.close()
```

como vez creo un rango de puertos que me gustaría ver si están abiertos. El argumento `socket()` especifica la familia de direcciones y el tipo `socket.AF_INET`  es la familia de direcciones de Internet para IPv4. `SOCK_STREAM` es el tipo de socket para TCP, el protocolo utilizado para transportar el mensaje en la red.

Fuentes:

- [https://www.pythonforbeginners.com](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/port-scanner-in-python/)
- https://realpython.com/python-sockets/
- https://pythonprogramming.net/python-port-scanner-sockets/

**POST no soy experto en python.**

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente!! Muchas gracias!! Me queda una duda, por qué for **port** funciona sin haberle asignado un valor?

Comment: @FrioEspacial a `port` si que se le asigna un valor, `port` es la variable asociada al ciclo `for` y en cada iteración toma el valor generado por éste al iterar sobre `range`. Es decir, el `for` va tomando valores del `range` y se los asigna a `port`, en la primera iteración `port` "vale" 1, en la segunda 2, etc Así hasta llegar a 1024, último entero generado por ese rango. Un saludo.

Comment: excelente comentario , no soy experto en python, entonces la variable definida asociadad al for , acumula los puertos hasta llegar a la cantidad de puertos que define el codigo ?